# environment configuration for tests running in NUnit

Tags: tfs, nunit

I have some integration tests that hit a webserver and verify certain functionalities.  Depending on the build environment, the server will be at a different address (http://localhost:8080/, http://test-vm/, etc).
  I would like to run these tests from a TFS build.

I'm wondering whats the appropriate way to configure these tests?  Would I just add a setting to the config file?  I'm doing that currently.  Incidentally we do have a separate branch per test environment, so I could have a different config file checked in for each environment.  I wonder if there is a better way though?

I'd like the build project to be able to tell the test what server to test.  This seems better because then I don't have to maintain config information on a per branch basis.

I believe I'd be using NUnit for Team Build (http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/) to get NUnit/TFS to play together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple options:

- [Edit the .config file via command line](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) before the test runs.
- If the setting depends on which machine the test is run from, you could put it in machine.config

Comment: yeah, looks like I'll use XmlUpdate from MSBuildTasks (http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)